# ¿Cómo comparar valores vacíos de datos primitivos?

Tags: java

Perdonen si es una pregunta tonta apenas comienzo en esto, por si acaso tengo 13 años :v

```
class Duda{

  public static void main (String[] args){

    int i;

      if(i== ){

      System.out.print("void");

      }

 }//final método main

}//final clase Duda
```

Comment: el i deberias comparlo con null para saber si tiene algun valor, asi if(i==null){} significa que no tiene ningun valor

Comment: Ninguna pregunta es tonta, solo hay que saber como preguntar para que los demás te podamos ayudar más fácil, date una vuelta por [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), ya que no indicas cual quieres que sea el resultado y lo que haz intentado.

Comment: pero "null" solo se puede usar con datos no primitivos.

Comment: el dato primitivo de tipo int, si no le das valor se inicia a 0, no es como una clase que si no la inicializas es null.

Answer (score 3):

En java los tipos primitivos, como int, no pueden contener un valor *vacío*, o `null`. Para ello, debes utilizar un tipo *nullable*, que es básicamente una clase y no un tipo primitivo.

En el caso de enteros, si necesitas un tipo *nullable*, utiliza la clase `Integer`.

```
class Duda{

  public static void main (String[] args){
    Integer i;
      if(i==null){
        System.out.print("void");
      }
 }//final método main

}//final clase Duda
```

Por otro lado, `int` siempre va a tener un valor. Hay casos donde puedes definir un valor *especial* que significa *vacío* (como 0 o -1), pero en general, esto no siempre es posible y *nunca* es recomendable.

Otros tipos *nullables* son: `Character`, `Long`, `Double`, `Byte`

Answer (score 0):

Es preferible que siempre inicialices las variable por ejemplo

`int a = 0;
float b = 0.0f;`

en dado caso de que sean cadenas

`String hola = " ";`

de esta forma evitaras esas circunstancias.
y no te preguntes por preguntar que es mejor que quedarse con la duda, a demás de que tu pregunta si esta bien formulada comparada con algunas de por aquí, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No siempre ocurre que sea necesario en Java inicializar la variables a utilizar, los variables declaradas pero que no son inicializadas explicitamente son inicializadas por el compilador a un valor por defecto el cual puede ser null o cero según el tipo de dato. Aún así es una mala práctica no inicializar las variables.

Los valores son inicializados por el compilador de acuerdo a lo siguiente:

- byte, short e int: 0
- long: 0L
- float: 0.0f
- double: 0.0d
- char: '\u0000'
- String o cualquier otro objeto: null
- boolean: false

Por lo tanto no hay valores vacíos para las variables primitivas, y dado esto no hay una forma de comparación de "vacíos"